# Sum of series with floor operation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have $2$ numbers $n$ and $a$ and series generated by these is

$f(i)=\lfloor\frac{n^2}{i}\rfloor$, $1 \leq i \leq a$

where $f(i)$ is the $i^{th}$ term in series

I want general formula for calculating 
$$\sum_{i=1}^af(i)$$
for any values of $n$ and $a$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a closed formula, but some things might be said. For example, if $a>n^2$, then there are terms in the sum which will be $0$, since $\lfloor n^2/i \rfloor=0$ for $i>n^2$. So your answer will depend on the relationship between $a$ and $n$, and you get a branching answer.

For example, if $n=2$, we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^a\Big\lfloor\frac{4}{i} \Big\rfloor=\begin{cases}
4,&\text{if }a=1\\
8,&\text{if }a\geq 4\\
4+a,&\text{otherwise (that is, the cases $a=2$ and $a=3$)}
\end{cases}
$$
You can also say that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\Big\lfloor\frac{n^2}{i} \Big\rfloor=\sum_{i=1}^a\Big\lfloor\frac{n^2}{i} \Big\rfloor
$$
for all $a\geq n^2$.